# Getting list of subcategory terms in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, custom-taxonomy

I am attempting to create section of my website footer that has link li of terms from a subcategory for a custom taxonomy I created.

```
register_taxonomy('producttype', 'product', array(
```

That is my custom taxonomy name along with my custom post type. I have tried something like this but it will not work.

```
<?php  
    echo '<ul class="products">';
    echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'product', '<li>', ',</li><li>', '</li>' );
    echo '</ul>';
?>
```

I have a subcategory that i created for the taxonomy producttype called Type I would like to get only those terms under the category Type.

I would appreciate the help

**Taxonomy function**

```
function add_custom_taxonomies() {
  // Add new "producttype" taxonomy to products
  register_taxonomy('producttype', 'product', array(
    // Hierarchical taxonomy (like categories)
    'hierarchical' => true,
    // This array of options controls the labels displayed in the WordPress Admin UI
    'labels' => array(
      'name' => _x( 'Producttypes', 'taxonomy general name' ),
      'singular_name' => _x( 'Producttype', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
      'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Producttypes' ),
      'all_items' => __( 'All Producttypes' ),
      'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Producttype' ),
      'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Producttype:' ),
      'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Producttype' ),
      'update_item' => __( 'Update Producttype' ),
      'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Producttype' ),
      'new_item_name' => __( 'New Producttype Name' ),
      'menu_name' => __( 'Product Type' ),
    ),
    // Control the slugs used for this taxonomy
    'rewrite' => array(
      'slug' => 'Producttype', // This controls the base slug that will display before each term
      'with_front' => false, // Don't display the category base before "/locations/"
      'hierarchical' => true // This will allow URL's like "/locations/boston/cambridge/"
    ),
  ));
}
add_action( 'init', 'add_custom_taxonomies', 0 );
```

Comment: are your sub-categories empty?

Comment: No @leftside I have created two type of categories in my custom taxonomy one is Company and the other Type i would like to display the terms under the category Type.

Comment: can you show the complete code for this taxonomy? `function your_taxonomy( ) {....` ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `wp_list_categories` rather than `get_the_term_list`, like this:

```
<ul class="products"> 
    <?php wp_list_categories('post_type=product&taxonomy=producttype&orderby=id&show_count=1&use_desc_for_title=0&child_of=8'); ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hello @Rich this code is automatically pulling from my post post-type not from my custom post type and the taxonomy associated with it.

Comment: Ive amended my answer to include a post type

Comment: Hello @Rich this does not seem to be working please refer to updated code that includes my tax name and custom post type

Comment: Have changed my code again, you will need to change the `child_of=8` to the ID of your Type term

Comment: `<ul class="products"> 
    <?php wp_list_categories('post_type= product&orderby=producttype&show_count=1&use_desc_for_title=0&child_of=Type'); ?>
</ul>` this is not working. I have changed the code to my post type, taxonomy id and the taxonmy category name.

Comment: Try again with the code above, I have added the taxonomy name in there for you 'producttype' you should use the ID of Type for the `child_of`

Comment: this code gives me my standard post categories for some reason it is not working

Comment: Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: I have tried something like so as well:

`<?php

$terms = get_terms('producttype');
foreach ($terms as $term) {

if($term->child == 0 ){

echo '<li>';
echo $term->name;
echo '</li>';
}
}
?>`
This just shows me a few children of the two parents i created I would like to target one parent term labelled "Type" and display all the child terms as links